# MVC Knockout bind to a List of ViewModels within a ViewModel

Tags: c#, json, mvvm, knockout.js

I have a ViewModel being passed to a View containing a List of another ViewModel such as

```
public class ThreadViewModel
{
    public Post post { get; set; }
    public UserStats user { get; set; }
    public List<ThreadReplyViewModel> comment { get; set; }
}
```

where ThreadReplyViewModel is such

```
public class ThreadReplyViewModel
{
    public PostComment comment { get; set; }
    public UserStats user { get; set; }
}`
```

My question is how do I create data-binds for the properties of the "comment" property of the ThreadReplyViewModel that is an element of the comment list. When I create the array for the List in ThreadViewModel it returns something like

```
[{"comment":{"PropertyName":Value,...}, "user":{"PropertyName":Value,...}}]
```

Instead of returning

```
[{"PropertyName":Value,...}, {"PropertyName":Value,...}]
```

I then try to access these property values with the following,

```
data-bind="text:comment.PropertyName"
```

or

```
data-bind="text:comment.comment.PropertyName"
```

My issue seems to be that when I call `JsonConvert.SerializeObject` on the List instead of returning a json string it returns an array of named json strings. I'm not sure how to got about handling the named objects in the json array, and so I don't know how to to create data-binds for the properties of the named objects.

p.s- I am fairly new to js/knockout as may be apparent in this post, as well as new to stackexchange, so if you need anymore info I will gladly update this post. here's to hoping the formatting is at least readable.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Unfortunately I can't help you with your problem, but I want to give you the advice to format your code on StackOverflow as described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) by indenting the code four spaces, after a blank line. This will allow proper code highlighting.

Comment: Your List<T> is getting converted to an array so you're probably looking for something like comment[0].comment.PropertyName. That only deals with the first element of the array though so you might need to use a "with" or "foreach" binding if you aren't already. It would be helpful if you included more of your view html